# Converting string to integer without losing the decimals number(s)

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to convert a string in to an integer in a Jinja template without losing the decimal numbers

I tried the following code which partially works;

`{{myfield|int}}`

The problem is that I loose any decimal numbers (5.5 becomes 5 for example) is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use float instead of int:

```
{{myfield | float}}
```